# The Truth Paradox

Tags: truth

**This is a paradox thought up by me, and I do not know if anything similar exists. Please do not accuse me of copying others.**

Assume that I am a schoolchild. One day, we have an assembly. Our principal challenges us to tell the truth for 24 days. **I **tell the truth**** by **saying that I cannot do it.** Did I fail the challenge or did I never start it? What else could have happened?

Comment: If your only assertion is "I cannot say the truth" the statement must be false, because if true it means that it is false: contradiction. Thus, you lose the game. If instead is true, it means that you are laying, in which case you are losing.

Comment: yea it's a bad question @MauroALLEGRANZA you would need to be told when the game started anyway hah

Comment: Welcome to the site! The Q&A nature of this site tends to revolve around asking technical questions about established philosophical literature rather than fostering what would be called metaphysical speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I voted to close the question based on the quality and nature of your question as I commented above, but I'll answer it anyway. Please don't take closure personal. We have some information on [what constitutes a good post here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

A [paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction) is a specific situation of language where one arrives at a contradiction of [propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition). There is nothing contradictory about your scenario.

If you are challenged to tell the truth for 24 days and then you honestly tell the truth the first day, but cannot tell the truth for days 2 to 24, then you have failed the challenge and there is no contradiction. Telling the truth for all 24 days is called a [necessary condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency). No statement contradicts another in this outcome. Some examples of philosophical paradoxes that most are familiar with are [Zeno's paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes).

Consider you want to exit a room. Anyone and everyone routinely does, so it is possible by [empirical experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_evidence). And yet, to leave a room you have to cross the halfway point to the exit. Then the next halfway point. Then the next. In fact, any distance has a halfway point, so there appears to be an infinite number of points to cross which seem to require some amount of time. Thus, one can conclude [rationally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalism), it's not possible to exit a room because one has to spend an infinite amount of time traveling to the exit. What gives? How is it possible I can exit and cannot exit the room? That [contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction) is what makes it a paradox. No contradiction, no paradox.

Anyway, feel free to rewrite your question after you read the guidance. Closures on this site happen frequently, and it might take a bit to get the knack of writing an acceptable question. Good luck!